# Basic Cross-Platform Avalonia app doesn't build

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, avaloniaui, avalonia

I try to create Android app in Avalonia. (.Net 7.0.400 in VS Code), But the Hello World refuses to build correctly on Android (simulator and physical device).

1. [Creating Cross Platform solution](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/developing-for-mobile/create-a-cross-platform-solution) worked fine, I have all the files generated
2. I installed Visual Studio 2022 with two checkboxes: .Net and MAUI
3. Next I moved to [Setting up environment for Android](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/developing-for-mobile/android/setting-up-your-developer-environment-for-android)
4. `dotnet workload install android` worked fine
5. `dotnet tool install -g Redth.Net.Maui.Check` worked fine
6. But here some issues started: 'maui-check' retruned an error:
   [image]
   Clicking `y` doesn't solve this issue:
   [image]
   (Reinstalling workload android also didn't solve this issue)
7. `dotnet build` works, but with warnings:
   [image]
8. But `dotnet run` returns an Error:
   [image]

```
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018: The "CompileAvaloniaXamlTask" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWor
ld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloW
orld\HelloWorld\obj\Debug\net7.0\Avalonia\original.pdb' because it is being used by another process. [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean ov 
erwrite) [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018:    at Avalonia.Build.Tasks.CompileAvaloniaXamlTask.Execute() in /_/src/Avalonia.Build.Task 
s/CompileAvaloniaXamlTask.cs:line 35 [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost 
.Execute() [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Users\OEM\.nuget\packages\avalonia\11.0.2\buildTransitive\AvaloniaBuildTasks.targets(120,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskE 
xecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.csproj]
```

I should also add that `HelloWorld.Desktop` works fine

I'd appreciate any help!

**[EDIT]**

9. I added `?` to `public Control? Build(object? data)` to file `HelloWorld\HelloWorld\ViewLocator.cs` and it resolved warnings.
10. I was also getting 70-ish warnings `JAVAC unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY`, but I managed to resolve them by `dotnet add package Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation --version 1.6.0.4`
11. At some point I noticed that after `dotnet build` `HelloWorld\HelloWorld.Android\bin\Debug\net7.0-android\com.CompanyName.HelloWorld-Signed.apk` and I am able install it on physical device (Redmi with Android 11). But as soon as I try to launch the app it shuts down
12. `dotnet clean` also doesn't change anything
13. I also tried different dotnet version using `global.json`, I trided `7.0.306`, `7.0.400` and `8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3`
14. Solution for error from point 8 seems to be killing all .NET processes in task manager, but it generates another error:

[image]

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.68\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(676,5): error XA0010: No available device. [C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\CP2\HelloWorld\HelloW 
orld.Android\HelloWorld.Android.csproj]
```

Comment: Its been a while for me, but can you run android using dotnet run, I remember using something like "dotnet build -t:Run /p:_DeviceName=<deviceID>" so that a proper emulator is loaded.

Comment: @mmix, `emulator -list-avds` returns two avds: 
 `Android_Emulator_33 `
 `Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 `

But running `dotnet build -t:Run /p:_DeviceName=Android_Emulator_33` returns the same error

Comment: I think you need an ID. try using adb devices -list